# How to optimize this MySql query - joins 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

This query is very slow. It is pretty simple and the 3 tables used are indexed on all columns in JOIN and WHERE clauses. How can I optimize my query, or my tables for this query?

This is the slow query. It takes 15-20 seconds to run.

```
 SELECT
    user.id,
    user.name,
    user.key,
    user.secret,
    account.id,
    account.name,
    account.admin,
    setting.attribute,
    setting.value
  FROM        user
  INNER JOIN  account ON account.id       = user.account_id
  INNER JOIN  setting ON setting.user_id  = user.id
    AND setting.deleted = 0
  WHERE user.deleted = 0
```

It is likely issue is caused by join on the setting table, because the below two queries take about 5 seconds total. Although, 5 seconds still seems a little long?

```
  SELECT
    user.id,
    user.name,
    user.user_key,
    user.secret,
    account.id,
    account.name,
    account.admin
  FROM        user
  INNER JOIN  account ON account.user_id = user.id
  WHERE user.deleted = 0

  SELECT
    setting.user_id,
    setting.attribute,
    setting.value
  FROM setting
  WHERE setting.deleted = 0
```

The explain for the slow query:

```
id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra

1, 'SIMPLE', 'user', 'ALL', 'PRIMARY,idx_id,idx_deleted', null, null, null, 600, 'Using where'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'account', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '8', 'user.account_id', 1, null
1, 'SIMPLE', 'setting', 'ref', 'attribute_version_unique,idx_user_id,indx_deleted', 'attribute_version_unique', '8', 'user.id', 35, 'Using where'
```

The schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    id BIGINT(20) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    user_key VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    secret VARCHAR(16),
    account_id BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    demo TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    details VARCHAR(4000),
    date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    date_modified DATETIME NOT NULL,
    deleted TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX idx_date_modified ON user (date_modified);
CREATE INDEX idx_deleted ON user (deleted);
CREATE INDEX idx_id ON pub_application (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name_unique ON user (user_key);
```

```
CREATE TABLE account
(
    id BIGINT(20) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    display_name VARCHAR(100),
    admin TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    visibility VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'public',
    cost DOUBLE,
    monthly_fee VARCHAR(300),
    date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    date_modified DATETIME NOT NULL,
    deleted TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0'
);
CREATE INDEX idx_date_modified ON account (date_modified);
```

```
CREATE TABLE setting
(
    id BIGINT(20) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    attribute VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(4000),
    date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    date_modified DATETIME NOT NULL,
    deleted TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX attribute_version_unique ON setting (user_id, attribute);
CREATE INDEX idx_user_id ON setting (user_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_date_modified ON setting (date_modified);
CREATE INDEX indx_deleted ON setting (deleted);
```

Comment: That's a well-formed question about query performance. Way to go!

Comment: You have only 600 rows in `users` and all joins used indexes so it query must execute fast. Maybe your problem in server?

Comment: I'm not really sure but I can't find index for `account_id` in `users` table and as i understand its foreign key for relation with `account` table.
While joining `ON account.id = user.account_id` it probably slows down whole query.

Comment: How many rows are in the result set for the slow query? It seems likely that you'll get at least as many rows as the size of your `settings` table. How many rows in each table? Have you thought about why you need to fetch all settings for every user at high speed? There's no magic that makes  transferring a large result set from your MySQL server to your client tremendously fast. SQL is good at finding needles in haystacks.  Copying entire haystacks from one place to another, not so much.

Comment: @O.Jones There are ~40k results, which is the number of rows in the settings table. This is an occasionally ran process which caches all results in memached, so this batch select is sensible. I thought this query was very slow, but possibly it's reasonable. Does 5 seconds to select 40k results seem reasonable to you? (And 15 seconds when selecting with a join?)

Comment: I ask myself, "how well would this work if I had a million?" of whatever I'm processing.  If you had a million user settings, the approach in your question would be a big bottleneck.  160K rows a minute isn't slow. But it's slower than interactive. 15 secs may work for you now, but it's just going to get worse as your system grows.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the feedback/advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect, you've stumbled across a common antipattern. Indexing "all columns" ordinarily is a *useless* move.  MySQL (as of late 2016) can exploit at most one index per table when satisfying a query. So the extra indexes are likely to help no queries, and definitely add overhead on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations.

*This* query might be improved by some purpose-designed compound covering indexes.

Try this index on your `user` table. It's a *covering index*: intended to contain all the columns necessary to satisfy the query. It's organized in an order that matches your `WHERE` clause.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_user_account_setting 
          ON user (deleted , account_id, id, name, key, secret);
```

This covering index might help on your `setting` table

```
CREATE INDEX idx_setting_user 
          ON setting (user_id, deleted , attribute, value);
```

Also try this one, switching the order of the first two columns, if the first one doesn't help.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_setting_user_alt
          ON setting (deleted, user_id, attribute, value);
```

Finally try this one on `account`.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_account_user 
          ON account (id, name, admin);
```

Please, if these suggestions help leave a brief comment telling how much they helped.

Read this. http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed advice, I will try this and report back. Do I need to remove the other indices to ensure the covering indices is used?

Comment: The covered indexes didn't make much difference. I found that selecting everything from the setting table with no where clause takes ~5 seconds, it has ~40k rows. 5 seconds seems pretty long? And if that query takes 5 seconds, it's not shocking that the join takes 15?